# RegEx for extracting latitude in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

```
    lrgstPlace = features[0]
    strLrgstPlace = str(lrgstPlace)
    longtide = re.match("r(lat=)([\-\d\.]*)",strLrgstPlace)
    print (longtide)
```

This is how my features list looks like

> Feature(place='28km S of Cliza, Bolivia', long=-65.8913, lat=-17.8571, depth=358.34, mag=6.3)
>   Feature(place='12km SSE of Volcano, Hawaii', long=-155.2005, lat=19.3258333, depth=6.97, mag=5.54)

Why does the regex cant match anything?Its just gives me "None" as a result.

Comment: Move the `r` out of the regex...

Comment: You also probably don't want to capture the "lat", but only the number that follows: r"lat=([\-\d\.]*)"

Comment: You might also want `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to put the r outside the quotes:
`r"(lat=)([\-\d\.]*)"`

Answer (score 0):

Your original expression works fine, we might want to slightly modify it, if we wish to just extract the lat numbers:

```
(?:lat=)([0-9\.\-]+)(?:,)
```

where `([0-9\.\-]+)` would capture our desired lat, and we wrap it with two non-capturing groups:

```
(?:lat=)
(?:,)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tStNMN/1/)

---

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?:lat=)([0-9\.\-]+)(?:,)"

test_str = "Feature(place='28km S of Cliza, Bolivia', long=-65.8913, lat=-17.8571, depth=358.34, mag=6.3) Feature(place='12km SSE of Volcano, Hawaii', long=-155.2005, lat=19.3258333, depth=6.97, mag=5.54)"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```